# Visual Basic, MySQL Update - Error during update command from app

Tags: vb.net, mysql-connector

I get an error message every time I try to update a customer database. The data is loaded from the database when a button "Edit" is clicked from a list view box, it loads the data based on customer row selection just fine, I proceed to make some changes to the customer info, I store the customer_id in a hidden box to use during the update procedure, the problem is that when I click the update button, it gives an error message about the customer_name or any field for that matter "Conversion from string "anydata" to type 'Integer' is not valid."
I declared all variables as string as can be seen in the code below but I don't know why the type 'Integer' is expected, if I type numbers in any of the boxes, it pharses it fine.

Why is this code trying to only accept integers to insert into the database?

```
                connection.Open()
                ' the 'edit' button has been clicked from the list of customers
                'Dim customerID As Integer = txtCustomerID.Text
                Dim customerName As String = txtName.Text
                Dim customerPhone As String = txtPhone.Text
                Dim customerEmail As String = txtEmail.Text
                Dim customerAddress As String = txtAddress.Text
                Dim customerCity As String = txtCity.Text
                Dim customerState As String = txtState.Text
                Dim customerZip As String = txtZip.Text

                ' Dim customerName As String()
                ' SQL query to insert data into the customers table
                Dim query As String = "UPDATE customers SET " &
                "customer_name = @customerName, " &
                "customer_phone = @customerPhone, " &
                "customer_email = @customerEmail, " &
                "customer_address = @customerAddress, " &
                "customer_city = @customerCity, " &
                "customer_state = @customerState, " &
                "customer_zip = @customerZip" &
                "WHERE customer_id = @customerID"

                ' Create a MySqlCommand with parameters
                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@customerName", customerName)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@customerPhone", customerPhone)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@customerEmail", customerEmail)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@customerAddress", customerAddress)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@customerCity", customerCity)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@customerState", customerState)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@customerZip", customerZip)

                ' Execute the UPDATE query
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("Customer information updated successfully.")
```

Changing cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue gives a generic error, when I change it to .add, it tells me of the data type error.

Please note that the same data is fine when performing a Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO customers (..." so, I'm leaning towards the "UPDATE customers SET " problem, not sure why.

Comment: `I declared all variables as string`  ... what is this => `Dim customerID As Integer`?

Comment: it is commented out, I tried that because that is in fact an int and is expected to be but that is not the issue in this case. Note that I also disabled the command to update into the table and from how fast I get that error, it is not like it is being rejected by the server, this is happening locally during variable value assignments.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was at the end of the sql query command variable definition. Specifically:

```
' SQL query to insert data into the customers table
Dim query As String = "UPDATE customers SET " &
"customer_name = @customerName, " &
"customer_phone = @customerPhone, " &
"customer_email = @customerEmail, " &
"customer_address = @customerAddress, " &
"customer_city = @customerCity, " &
"customer_state = @customerState, " &
"customer_zip = @customerZip" &          <=== NO SPACE AFTER "...Zip"
"WHERE customer_id = @customerID"
```

I did not space after @customerZip" <-- this would join @customerZip to WHERE since I did not put a space at the end of Zip. I feel dumb lol. Unfortunately, Visual Basic Studio cannot detect this type of error when using double quotes.

EDIT:

The way to avoid the likelihood of such an error is to use a multiline string literal:

```vb
' SQL query to insert data into the customers table
Dim query As String = "UPDATE customers SET
                       customer_name = @customerName,
                       customer_phone = @customerPhone,
                       customer_email = @customerEmail,
                       customer_address = @customerAddress,
                       customer_city = @customerCity,
                       customer_state = @customerState,
                       customer_zip = @customerZip
                       WHERE customer_id = @customerID"
```

Comment: Ah! good catch. Thanks for posting the fix to the issue. I wasn't sure about commented-out thing mentioned earlier, as I'm not sure how nested `'` are handled within a comment line.

Comment: This is an example of why you should not use this type of string concatenation to build SQL code. VB has supported multiline string literals for some time now and it has always supported XML literals, so there's no reason to make your code hard to read and therefore more error-prone by using concatenation like this. Use a multiline string literal and then you can't omit a space like this.

Comment: @jmcilhinney agreed, however the in-line is usually very long and I have to scroll a lot lol, next time I will know but this makes it ready for me as I can relate it to each of the variable assignments as well, I will just be more careful with spacing.

Comment: You wouldn't have to scroll any more than you do now. No line would be longer than it is now and the number of lines would be the same as it is now. I think you missed the point: use a MULTILINE string literal. I have edited your answer to demonstrate.